# Как правильно взять JSON из таблицы?

Tags: php, mariadb

Использую MariaDB. Код

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('0.0.0.0', 'root' , '');
$createDB = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db';
$createTABLE = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GAMERS (name)';
$dbResult = mysqli_query($conn, $createDB);
echo $dbResult;
$tableResult = mysqli_query($conn, $createTABLE);
$return_arr = array();
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$fetch = $conn->query("SELECT name FROM GAMERS");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Выводит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Делаю в смартфоне, вот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD**

Переписал скрипт вот так

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'db');
$createDB = 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db';
$createTABLE = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS GAMERS (name)';
$dbResult = mysqli_query($conn, $createDB);
echo $dbResult;
$tableResult = mysqli_query($conn, $createTABLE);
$return_arr = array();
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$fetch = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM GAMERS");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$row_array['name'] = $row['name'];
array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Теперь вот

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'db.gamers' doesn't exist in /storage/emulated/0/www/public/connect.php on line 10

Comment: а что за подключение такое `0.0.0.0` ? Куда коннект?

Comment: Это локальный сервер (и хост). Делаю в смартфоне. Я вообще вот два часа как в это дело залез :)

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - вот это локальный хост

Comment: @Михаил, дополнил вопрос скрином

Comment: Попробуйте сначала проверить подключение вообще `mysqli_connect_error`, а потом уже все остальные действия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После создания базы данных нужно выполнить запрос на использование данной БД:

```
USE db_name;
```

Плюс неплохо было бы использовать апострофы "`" (без кавычек) при написании названии таблиц.

Comment: Не помогло, та же ошибка